# bq load and I get "Too many positional args - still have [..."

Tags: command-line, load, google-bigquery

I am attempting to load data from Cloud Storage into a table and am getting the error message below.

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1  --field_delimiter='\t' --source_format=CSV projectID:dataset.table gs://bucket/source.txt sku:STRING,variant_id:STRING,title:STRING,category:STRING,description:STRING,buy_url:STRING,mobile_url:STRING,itemset_url:STRING,image_url:STRING,swatch_url:STRING,availability:STRING,issellableonline:STRING,iswebexclusive:STRING,price:STRING,saleprice:STRING,quantity:STRING,coresku_inet:STRING,condition:STRING,productreviewsavg:STRING,productreviewscount:STRING,mediaset:STRING,webindexpty:INTEGER,NormalSalesIndex1:FLOAT,NormalSalesIndex2:FLOAT,NormalSalesIndex3:FLOAT,SalesScore:FLOAT,NormalInventoryIndex1:FLOAT,NormalInventoryIndex2:FLOAT,NormalInventoryIndex3:FLOAT,InventoryScore:FLOAT,finalscore:FLOAT,EDVP:STRING,dropship:STRING,brand:STRING,model_number:STRING,gtin:STRING,color:STRING,size:STRING,gender:STRING,age:STRING,oversized:STRING,ishazardous:STRING,proddept:STRING,prodsubdept:STRING,prodclass:STRING,prodsubclass:STRING,sku_attr_names:STRING,sku_attr_values:STRING,store_id:STRING,store_quantity:STRING,promo_name:STRING,product_badge:STRING,cbl_type_names1:STRING,cbl_type_value1:STRING,cbl_type_names2:STRING,cbl_type_value2:STRING,cbl_type_names3:STRING,cbl_type_value3:STRING,cbl_type_names4:STRING,cbl_type_value4:STRING,cbl_type_names5:STRING,cbl_type_value5:STRING,choice1_name_value:STRING,choice2_name_value:STRING,choice3_name_value:STRING,cbl_is_free_shipping:STRING,isnewflag:STRING,shipping_weight:STRING,masterpath:STRING,accessoriesFlag:STRING,short_copy:STRING,bullet_copy:STRING,map:STRING,display_msrp:STRING,display_price:STRING,suppress_sales_display:STRING,margin:FLOAT
```

I have also tried to load the schema into a json file and I get the same error message.

Comment: What command are you running to use the schema from a JSON file? Could you post the contents of the schema JSON file? Do you have a minimal example CSV file that still shows this error?

Comment: Looks like you have two "load" args on the command line.

Comment: To load the JSON, I would using this script

bq load --skip_leading_rows=1  --field_delimiter='\t' --source_format=CSV load projectID:dataset.table gs://bucket/source.txt schema.json

Answer (score 1):

As this was too big for comment, will post it here.

I wonder what happens if you set the schema file to have this content:

```
[{"name": "sku", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "variant_id", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "title", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "category", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "description", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "buy_url", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "mobile_url", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "itemset_url", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "image_url", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "swatch_url", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "availability", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "issellableonline", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "iswebexclusive", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "price", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "saleprice", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "quantity", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "coresku_inet", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "condition", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "productreviewsavg", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "productreviewscount", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "mediaset", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "webindexpty", "type": "INTEGER"},
 {"name": "NormalSalesIndex1", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "NormalSalesIndex2", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "NormalSalesIndex3", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "SalesScore", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "NormalInventoryIndex1", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "NormalInventoryIndex2", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "NormalInventoryIndex3", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "InventoryScore", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "finalscore", "type": "FLOAT"},
 {"name": "EDVP", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "dropship", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "brand", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "model_number", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "gtin", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "color", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "size", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "gender", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "age", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "oversized", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "ishazardous", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "proddept", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "prodsubdept", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "prodclass", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "prodsubclass", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "sku_attr_names", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "sku_attr_values", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "store_id", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "store_quantity", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "promo_name", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "product_badge", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_names1", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_value1", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_names2", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_value2", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_names3", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_value3", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_names4", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_value4", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_names5", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_type_value5", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "choice1_name_value", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "choice2_name_value", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "choice3_name_value", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "cbl_is_free_shipping", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "isnewflag", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "shipping_weight", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "masterpath", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "accessoriesFlag", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "short_copy", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "bullet_copy", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "map", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "display_msrp", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "display_price", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "suppress_sales_display", "type": "STRING"},
 {"name": "margin", "type": "FLOAT"}]
```

If you save it say in file "schema.json" and run the command:

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1  --field_delimiter='\t' --source_format=CSV projectID:dataset.table gs://bucket/source.txt schema.json
```

Do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Cherba nailed it. The typo was in my batch file that included the extra load parameter. Thanks for all your time consideration.